# Why is the sizeof() a char array sometimes sizeof(void *) and sometimes sizeof(the array)?

Tags: c, sizeof

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printS(char []);

int main(){
    char str[]="The C Programming Language"; 
    printf("%d \n",sizeof(str)); //output=27
    printS(str);
}

void printS(char s[]){
    printf("%d \n",sizeof(s)); //output=4
}
```

Why this anamolous output

please explain what is the difference between 'str' and 's'....
and how can i have sizeof() output=27 in printS function.

Comment: In intro classes, we are often taught that arrays are pointers, and pointers are arrays.  This is **not** true.  They are similar in many ways, but not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass an array to a function like you are it will decay to a pointer and therefore `sizeof` will be returning the size of a pointer not the size of the array. The [C Faq's section on Arrays and Pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/) is a great reference and [Question 6.4](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html) covers this exact issue. The relevant section of the C99 draft standard is section `6.3.2.1` *Lvalues, arrays, and function designators* paragraph *3* which says(emphasis mine):

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or is a
>   string literal used to initialize an array, an **expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is
>   converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of
>   the array object** and is not an lvalue.

In order to obtain the length of a C style string you can use `strlen` from `string.h` header file.

Answer (score 3):

The value of `sizeof()` is the size of one variable of the specified type. `s` is actually `char*`, so `sizeof(s)` is 4 (on your 32-bit platform). In `main()`, `str` is treated as an array of char, so `sizeof(str)` is the size of the array. Note that the length of "The C Programming Language" is 26, the extra one byte is for the zero terminator.

To get the length of `s`, use `strlen(s)`. This time the zero terminator is not counted. And don't forget to `#include <string.h>` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

C does not have the feature of passing array values. Arrays are always passed as pointers, when you declare a parameter of type `foo[]` you are effectively declaring `foo *`.